# ggplot sort order treatment of NA values

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, na

My goal is to create a scatter plot of requests for service.
The X axis will be the date the request was made.
X values will show dates from oldest to newest, left to right.
The Y axis will show the priority assigned to the request.
I wish to order the Y values from highest priority at the top (i.e., 1) to lowest.
Requests which haven't been prioritized have NA in that column.

Here is a sample data set (NOTE - the original data file id tab-separated with no values in the position where "NA" is shown below for clarity's sake):

```
ID  Priority    DateCreated  
549 NA  2018-02-15  
548 NA  2018-02-15  
547 3   2018-02-13  
537 1   2018-01-17  
536 5   2018-01-17  
518 NA  2017-12-21  
509 3   2017-11-27  
500 2   2017-11-16  
486 NA  2017-10-04  
477 3   2017-08-08  
475 1   2017-09-14  
448 2   2017-07-21  
444 5   2017-07-14  
431 5   2017-06-30  
425 1   2017-06-21  
407 2   2017-05-26  
395 4   2017-05-09  
394 4   2017-05-09  
374 4   2017-04-27  
368 2   2017-04-21  
352 NA  2017-04-03  
328 4   2017-02-28  
308 NA  2017-02-28  
272 2   2016-10-05  
213 4   2016-05-19  
212 5   2016-05-19  
200 2   2016-04-26  
188 NA  2016-03-17
```

After loading ggplot2 and data.frame, I create the plot with this code:

```
bl <- fread("backlog.txt")  
bl$DateCreated <- as.Date(bl$DateCreated, "%Y-%m-%d")  
bl$Priority <- as.integer(bl$Priority)  
ggplot(bl, aes(x = DateCreated, y = reorder(Priority, -Priority))) +  
 geom_text((aes(label = ID)))
```

If you reproduce this plot, you will see that the items with a priority of NA appear at the top. For presentation to my customer, it is much clearer if they appear at the bottom.
I suppose I could replace the NAs with a "magic number" (e.g., 11), but I'd prefer a less kludgey solution.
Anyone dealt with a similar issue already?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a workaround as well but I think more acceptable than setting a 'magic number'

```
bl$DateCreated <- as.Date(bl$DateCreated, "%Y-%m-%d") 
bl$Priority[is.na(bl$Priority)] <- "No Data Available"
bl$Priority <- factor(bl$Priority,levels=c("No Data Available","1","2","3","4","5"))
ggplot(bl, aes(x = DateCreated, y = Priority)) +  geom_text((aes(label = ID)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your interest! If no one comes up with a neater solution, yours looks good, and is way better than the "magic number" kludge I was facing.